# How do you create scripts for Buildout?

Tags: buildout

I'm trying to build a commandline project in Buildout and I'm not exactly sure how to define scripts to be built to the bin directory. I remember seeing this ability somewhere, but I can't remember where and the documentation isn't so good :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zc.recipe.egg: Script generation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.egg/2.0.0a1#script-generation).  zc.recipe.egg is actually *part* of zc.buildout, but you're right, there should be at least a clear pointer somewhere that the zc.buildout documentation isn't complete if you're dealing with python distributions in a buildout until you've read the docs for zc.recipe.egg.

Comment: `z3c.recipe.scripts` should be a newer alternative of `zc.recipe.egg`.

Comment: Not any more: buildout 2.0 dropped the half-baked site-package isolation features of buildout 1.5, and went back to using zc.recipe.egg.

z3c.recipe.egg is only usable with buildout 1.5 through 1.7.

Answer (score 6):

Eggs *setup.py* is the place to define the scripts. Given the package is named mypackage with a main.py in there and a run function - it looks like so:

```
setup(
  ...    
  entry_points={
    'console_scripts': ['myscriptname = mypackage.main:run'],
  },
  ...
)
```

In buildout then you just use *zc.recipe.egg:script* recipe:

```
[buildout]
parts = myscripts

[myscript]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:script
eggs = mypackage
```

After buildout runs theres a executeable file *./bin/myscriptname*.